# Error : No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a .Net app linked to an Oracle database with a user defined type like this :

```
create or replace TYPE Person as object (firstname varchar2(50),lastname varchar2(50));
```

The UDT is reflected at the application level with the following object :

```vb
<OracleCustomTypeMapping("SCHEMA.PERSON")>
Public Class Person
    Implements IOracleCustomType
    Implements IOracleCustomTypeFactory
    Implements INullable

    Private FirstName_ As String

    <OracleObjectMapping("FIRSTNAME")>
    Public Property FirstName As String
        Get
            Return FirstName_
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            FirstName_ = value
            IsNull_ = False
        End Set
    End Property


    Private LastName_ As String

    <OracleObjectMapping("LASTNAME")>
    Public Property LastName As String
        Get
            Return LastName_
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            LastName_ = value
            IsNull_ = False
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        IsNull_ = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub FromCustomObject(Connection As OracleConnection, Pointer As IntPtr) Implements IOracleCustomType.FromCustomObject
        OracleUdt.SetValue(Connection, Pointer, "FIRSTNAME", FirstName)
        OracleUdt.SetValue(Connection, Pointer, "LASTNAME", LastName)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ToCustomObject(Connection As OracleConnection, Pointer As IntPtr) Implements IOracleCustomType.ToCustomObject
        FirstName = CStr(OracleUdt.GetValue(Connection, Pointer, "FIRSTNAME"))
        LastName = CStr(OracleUdt.GetValue(Connection, Pointer, "LASTNAME"))

        IsNull_ = False
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateObject() As IOracleCustomType Implements IOracleCustomTypeFactory.CreateObject
        Return New Person
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IsNull As Boolean Implements INullable.IsNull
        Get
            Return IsNull_
        End Get
    End Property

    Private IsNull_ As Boolean = True
End Class
```

The communication between the application object and the database object works well. I can load data from database, however when trying to save databack to the database, I have the error : No parameterless constructor defined for this object. I have no idea where this error is coming from since my object has indeed a parameterless constructor.

I try to save databack to the database using DataAdapter.

```vb
'Load data from database
Command = New OracleCommand("Select * from MyTable", Connection)
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
DataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, "MyTable")
DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "MyTable")
DataTable = DataSet.Tables("MyTable")

'Make some change
'Change some rows values
'...

'Save databack to the database
DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)   '<<<< Where the error is raised
```

Here is the stack trace :

```
  Stack trace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
```

Anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks, Cheers,

Comment: *"I have no idea where this error is coming"*.  Then look at the stack trace for exception.  That's what it's for.

Comment: I looked to the stack trace, but it gives nothing explicit. The error is raised by internal system libraries. Any ideas please ? I added the stack trace btw